# "Fell off X and landed in Y"

Tags: idiom-requests

I remember hearing a phrase that meant someone had a stroke of bad luck that ended up good - "he fell off X and landed in Y" - but I can't remember what X and Y were.

This was something said by my grandparents (WWII-era, southern Plains US). Has anyone else heard it, or is it a very localized/generational idiom?

Comment: Well, there's always "Out of the frying pan, into the fire."

Comment: https://twitter.com/drunkmikelange?lang=en

Comment: He wants an example of bad luck becoming good, so "out of the fire, into the frying pan" seems more accurate ;)

Comment: The phrase "landed in clover" leaps to mind.

Comment: How about "He fell into a pile of [stinking stuff] and came up smelling of roses"? The idiom "Out of the frying pan, into the fire." refers to someone who escaped one bad situation and found themself in another bad one.

Comment: You can google "fell off * landed in *" and get wild-card matches, but the main result is that a lot of things are falling off airplanes. Nothing showed up.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard "They fell into the river and came up with a salmon" though that might also be a localised idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact match, the archetypal

- *He fell into a pile of [stinking stuff] and came up smelling of roses.*

is given by Rosie F.

She used euphemism; the usual expression is just 'He came up smelling of roses'.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20out%2Fup%20smelling%20like%2Fof%20roses) has

> **come out/up smelling like/of roses**  [idiom] [informal]:
>
> to have success or good fortune in a situation in which one was likely
> to fail, be harmed, etc.
>
> - *The scandal forced several board members to resign, but the chairman came out smelling like roses.*